# Как можно сделать 301-й редирект в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Может подскажет кто-то... Как можно сделать 301-й редирект с /index.php?c=news&newsId=84 на /?p=219 в .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=news&newsId=84 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /?p=219 [R=301,L]
```

Либо так:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.php\?c=news&newsId=84$ /?p=219 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `Либо так:` работать точно не будет.

Comment: @Visman, почему?

Comment: Потому что RewriteRule не видит get переменные.